# How to save data into JSON to specified keys? For Python 3.7

Tags: python, json

I have little script on python and I want receive results into JSON file.

I prepared already JSON keys with names of tests.

It looks like this one:

```
{
    "key1" : ""
    "key2" : ""
    "key3" : ""

}
```

And now I want to save results (usual str (after if else tests)) as value into specified key.

How can I perform it?

Thank you!

EDIT: not create dictionary, not take FROM JSON. Only write to specified key.

Like (by script, of course):

"Write 'my_str' to My_json[My_key]"

Comment: Is the JSON you pasted in your question being read into the python program, or is it a dictionary that you want to convert to JSON?

Comment: We would need to see your values and how you get them to be able to help you insert them into json

Comment: Being read (using load)

Comment: Usual str 'Test "my_tests" passed/failed''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to save dictionary into a json format you should use json lib which allows you to dump a dictionary in a json file and convert convert a .json into a python dictionary

```
import json

my_dict = {'key1':'', 'key2':'', 'key3':''}

def dump_data(data):
    with open('file.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

def read_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

dump_data(my_dict)
my_dict2 = read_data('file.json')
```

Comment: Keys already exist. I want to add values to existed keys.

Comment: `my_dict = read_data('file.json')
for key, value in zip(my_dict.keys(), your_values):
     my_dict[key] = value

dump_data(my_dict)`

Comment: Read - to take data FROM JSON, I want to add data TO JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can `import json`, create a dictionary, and use:

```
    json_var = json.dumps(dict_var)
```

To transform it in json. See [Python JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).